# How to unbind port after interrupting stress-ng dccp stresser

Tags: linux, stress-ng, dccp

hello everyone i have the task to run stress-ng with --dccp stresser, but i accidentally interrupt it while it was working and now i can't run it again.

```
sudo stress-ng --dccp 1 --timeout 60s --metrics-brief
stress-ng: info:  [35478] setting to a 1 min, 0 secs run per stressor
stress-ng: info:  [35478] dispatching hogs: 1 dccp
stress-ng: fail:  [35480] dccp: bind failed, errno=98 (Address already in use)
stress-ng: error: [35478] dccp: [35480] terminated with an error, exit status=2 (stressor failed)
stress-ng: metrc: [35478] stressor       bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s     bogo ops/s
stress-ng: metrc: [35478]                           (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [35478] skipped: 0
stress-ng: info:  [35478] passed: 0
stress-ng: info:  [35478] failed: 1: dccp (1)
stress-ng: info:  [35478] metrics untrustworthy: 0
stress-ng: info:  [35478] unsuccessful run completed in 0.00 secs
```

I thought that i need to free port, but when i use sudo netstat -nutlp to watch ports, i don't see stress-ng process that capture any port[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwsS.png).
So can you help me to solve this problem to rebind smth and rerun my stresser

Answer (score 0):

Either wait a few minutes for the ports to become free, or re-run with a different port range using the --dccp-port option